# Uploading MonoDroid app to Android Market

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am trying to load an app to the Android Market. Below are the instructions I am using from the following website to prepare my application for submission:

http://android.xamarin.com/Documentation/Guides/Preparing_Package_for_Android_Marketplace

This following message is at the beginning of the instructions.  But no instructions on how to add this to the AndroidManifest.xml file.

In order for the Android Market to accept your application, it must
define an application     level    icon.  Ensure a line like this
exists in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:label="MyApplication" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
```

A future release will provide better support for setting this.

The very first item has me stumped because I am getting the following error when I try to upload my application to the Market.

**"The icon path specified by the manifest is not in the apk."**

My question is, how do I add the application level icon statement to the manifest file?

Thanks.

p.s. The app deploys to both the emulator and local Android device in debug and release modes with no errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a manifest file to your project by bringing up the property pages for your project, going to the Android Manifest tab, and doing the 'add AndroidManifest.xml' link.

Now there should be a file called "AndroidManifest.xml" in the Properties folder in your project.

Add the line specified to this file, replacing any existing  element.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it had nothing to do with the icon. I had an application class (GlobalVars extends Applications) and this was defined in the manifest as different: `<application android:name=".GlobalVars" />` I deleted this and added `android:name="com.example.myapp.GlobalVars"` to the application declaration.

If it is the icon you may have drawable-hdpi, -ldpi, -mdpi folders, and no drawable folder. Or have a drawable folder but the icon is not in it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the relevant snippet from your AndroidManifest.xml file?  Whatever you have as the android:icon attribute ("@drawable/icon" in the example) is what the apk will be looking for.  You can set this manually in the xml file, or by using the wizard in the ADT plugin for Eclipse.  If this is set correctly, this means you should have a file called icon.png in one of your drawable folders.  If you don't have an icon.png, can you post your folder structure?

In an app I've uploaded to the market, I have the same attribute - @drawable/icon - in my manifest, and therefore I am required to have a file called icon.png in my project.  In my case, I have three different icon.png files in my various density-based drawable folders (res/drawable-hdpi, res/drawable-mdpi, res/drawable-ldpi).  In your case, you need to at least have res/drawable/icon.png.

Comment: This is my Activity attribute and the icon is in the Resources/Drawable folder marked as AndroidResource. This is a MonoDroid app, so I am using Visual Studio 2010 as my IDE. I'm still looking for a way to add the     <application android:label="MyApplication" android:icon="@drawable/icon">  to the AndroidManifest.xml file prior to compile so it is added to the apk.

Comment: I haven't used MonoDroid before, so I might be missing something.  Is the icon called AndroidResource.png?  If it is, your tag should be <application android:label="MyApplication" android:icon="@drawable/androidresource" (and you should rename the file...android resource file names are supposed to be all lower case).  If you're asking how to add that tag to the file, can you open the xml file in a text editor like notepad and add it in there?  I'm sorry if these questions/answers seem dumb, I'm not completely understanding what is going on.

Comment: To get past the "icon path" error, I changed the icon name from "myicon.png" to the standard "icon.png".  This fixed the following error message: "The icon path specified by the manifest is not in the apk",  Now I get the message: "The file is invalid: ERROR: dump failed because no AndroidManifest.xml found ",   I think it may be time to put MonoDroid on the shelf.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also be generated if the manifest xml includes more than one < application > node.